# 0-100 smart player rating system

Tags: logic, probability, rating

I need to come up with a 0-100 smart player rating system.

I need to meet the following conditions:

1) If a player with lesser rating beats a player with a higher rating - both player's rating change should be greater then if an opposite result were the outcome.

2) Rating increase should slow down towards 100

3) Rating decrease should slow down towards 0

4) Minimum rating change should be 0.1

5) Maximum rating change should be 10

What would be a logical response, or approach to follow towards the solution?

I have tried to work Elo as well as writing formulas of my own, to no success.

ex.

If **R**a<**R**b and **R**a wins >>>>>>>>

**R**a'= **R**a+(**R**b-**R**a)(max.ratingvalue-current.ratingvalue)/100

**R**b'= **R**b+(**R**b-**R**a)(current.ratingvalue-min.ratingvalue)/100

Comment: you might want to google 'ELO rating'

Comment: I  have already done it, as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Let the first player's rating be x and the second players rating be y

After the match say if x wins and x > y

```
x += max ( min( ((x-y) * -((x - 50)^2)/25 + 100) 10), 0.1)
x = max(min(x, 100), 0.1)
```

The min and max ensures we stay within the allowable range
The function `-((x - 50)^2)/25 + 100` makes more sense when put in Desmos or some other graphing software[image]

As you can see the scale decrease towards zero as they approach the extremes

You will need to play with this a bit especially the scales for the function as I whipped it up quick but hopefully it should get you on the right track and allow you to come up with the equations for the other situations ie) x wins and x < y etc